# File upload in CodenameOne Browser component

Tags: codenameone

The native file chooser dialog doesn't get invoked from within a BrowserComponent. I understand WebView has some limitations but there are ways to overcome this in Android.

Is there a workaround for CodenameOne? Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit problematic because Android overcame it in a non-portable way. That means the workaround worked for older versions of Android, stopped working and then you needed a new workaround all the time.

But it was even more problematic because of permissions that made it really hard to do it well especially with Android 6+ permission types. All users that asked for this so far found a different way to implement file upload e.g. using the multipart class so this never became an issue that required a workaround (which would be non-trivial).

Comment: Appreciate the quick and detailed response. Let me weigh my options.